# The code Doesnt work while Checking for 2 buttons pressing using GetAsyncKeyState and work when checking for 1 Key

Tags: c++, hotkeys

I'm trying to type a code that will show my program when the user press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> but the code doesn't work when I type it like that ( to check for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> )

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(16+115))
{
    ShowWindow(mainhwnd,SW_SHOW);
}
```

but if I type it like that (to check for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> only or <kbd>S</kbd> only) will work!

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(16))
{
    ShowWindow(mainhwnd,SW_SHOW);
}
```

and the problem is not that the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key changes the case of the letter so the ASCII code of it changed. I try with the ASCII code of the 2 cases and try to replace 16 (the ASCII code of shift key) with `VK_LSHIFT` and `VK_RSHIFT` and `SHIFT_PRESSED` and it doesn't work too

I'm using codeblocks

Comment: Cant you just call GetAsyncKeyState twice?

Comment: @Eric i cant get you , are you asking about calling GetAsyncKeyState fucn twice ?!
now , i called it once as you see,whats the problem with my code ?